# How to pull a report on last modified date for attachments

Tags: reporting

I am very new to Salesforce and would like to know if there is any way to pull a report based on last modified date for attachments.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you cannot report on attachments but you can look at custom solutions like [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41477/is-there-a-way-to-report-on-attachments) to implement your functionality.

if you want to report on files and content then thats possible check this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrhNAAS) out

If you are using salesforce classic i would suggest you migrate to lightning experience and use files to use the reporting features available in it